# Php - Stopping a thread when it exceeds timeout

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I'm looking for a way to stop/kill a thread when it takes too long to do its task. I'm on CentOS 7, PHP 7.2.12.
I've tried to use the Threaded::kill() method only to find out it no longer exists. I'm open to either stopping the thread from either within the thread itself or the main thread.

Below is code for context, I'm trying to call apis in parallel.

```
$finalReport = array();

$timeout = 5;
$sources = array(new PullReport(new MakeDataSource("")), new PullReport(new ModelDataSource("")));
$startTime = time();
$isPending = true;
foreach ($sources as $source) {
    //echo $source->get();
    $source->start();
    $source->join();
}


foreach ($sources as $source) {
    while (!$source->getDataSource()->hasData()) {
        if (time() - $startTime > $timeout) {
            $source->kill();
            break;
        }
        echo "no data";
        usleep(100);
    }
}

foreach ($sources as $source) {
    $finalReport[] = $source->data;
}
print_r($finalReport);
```

Edit: Alternatively What are some alternatives to killing the thread outright?

Comment: Where is the threaded code and what threading mechanism are you using?  PECL Pthreads has been discontinued, but generally you have a semaphore that gets set when you call your own kill or stop method.  `public function run() { while($this->isRunning) { /* Do Work */ } }`  Then your `stop()` method just sets `$this->isRunning = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Use [symfony process and set timeout](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#process-timeout).
However, consider to use queue like RabbitMq.